# Make changes in one table with regard to data from another table

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

I have a project for task management.

Weekends are non-working days, so it is highlighted in pink

```js
function isWorkDayNov(date, month = 10, year = 2020) {
  const weekDay = new Date(year, month, date).getDay()
  return  weekDay !== 0 && weekDay !== 6; 
}

function DateCellNov({date}) {
  return <td className={isWorkDayNov(date) ? 'workday' : 'weekend'}>{date}</td>
}

class HomePage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="main">
                <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th colSpan="7">Nov</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th colSpan="7">Week 1</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                            {
                                [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22].map(date => <DateCellNov key={date} date={date} />)
                            }
                        </tr>
                 </tbody>
                </table>
                <br></br>
                <div>
                  <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th colSpan="4">Table 2</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Task</th>
                            <th>Time</th>
                            <th>Start Date</th>
                            <th>End Date</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Task 1</td>
                            <td>16 Hrs</td>
                            <td>17-Nov-2020</td>
                            <td>18-Nov-2020</td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<HomePage />, document.querySelector('#app'))
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    
  }
  th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;   
    
  }
  .weekend {
    background-color: pink;
  }
  .workday {
    background-color: white;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" />
```

In table 2 it is given that task1 will take 16hrs to complete, considering there are 8hrs of working day, which means that task1 will be completed in 2 days(8*2=16). How can I take this information and change the background-color of 17th and 18th Nov?

Comment: You need to put the values of table 2 in a state so you can refer to them in the table 1 and highlight the days

Comment: @JulianKleine Can you please give an example on how to do it?